# Embedding methods into implicit Runge-Kutta schemes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I was reading through [Hairer's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540604529) for stiff ODEs, and while mainly looking at the theory, I ended up reading chapter IV.8 on implementation details, just to write a toy program to see  things in action. In said section of the book, the author proposes an embedded scheme for the RadauIIA method, such that:
$$
\hat{y_1}-y_1 =\gamma_0 h f(x_0, y_0) + \sum_i (\hat{b}_i-b_i)hf(x_0+c_i h,g_i) = \gamma_0 h f(x_0, y_0) + \sum_i e_i z_i
$$
concluding that for $\hat{y}_1 - y_1 = \mathcal{O}(h^4)$, it is needed that
$$
\left(e_1, e_2, e_3\right)=\frac{\gamma_0}{3}(-13-7\sqrt{6},-13+7\sqrt{6},-1).
$$
This implies that $e_i = \hat{b}_i-b_i$, therefore:
$$
 \hat{b}_i = b_i + e_i = \left( \dfrac{16-\sqrt{6}}{36}, \dfrac{16+\sqrt{6}}{36} , \dfrac{1}{9}\right) + e_i
$$
The vector $b_i$ is well known for the 3-stage RadauIIA method (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Radau_IIA_methods)). In fact, for the (augmented) embedded method, these are 4-element vectors, with $e_0 = \gamma_0$ and $b_0 = 0$.

My questions are:

1. Any insights on how to get such values for $e_i$?
2. Looking at the first part of the error term, $\gamma_0 h f(x_0, y_0)$, implies $c_0 = 0$ and $a_{1j} = 0$. No more function evaluations and/or stages are computer. Is it then safe to assume that the Butcher *tableau* of the embedded method has the representation:
   $$
   \begin{array}{c|c c}
   0 & 0 & \{0\}^T \\
   c & \{0\} & A \\ \hline 
   & 0 & b^T \\   \hline
   & \gamma_0 & \hat{b}^T \\ 
   \end{array}
   $$
3. Does this new method need not satisfy the simplifying assumptions, namely:
   $$
   B(p) = \sum_i^s b_i c_i^{q-1}=\dfrac{1}{q}, \qquad q=1, ..., p \\
   C(\eta) = \sum_i^s a_{ij} c_j^{q-1}=\dfrac{c_i^q}{q}, \qquad i=1,...,s, \quad q=1, ..., \eta
   $$
   $C(\eta)$ is satisfied, since the new elements (assuming the previous tableaux is correct) are all zeros, but $B(p)$ is not (with $\gamma_0 \ne 0$). However a different choice of $\hat{b}_i$ can be used in order to satisfy it.

Thank you.

EDIT: Point 2) has been edited since it was partially answered in the paragraphs preceding it.